# nuget error: the path for the selected source could not be resolved

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Nuget in Visual studio can't access a custom package source location on a shared network drive.  I am able to browse the nuget.org and microsoft packages just fine.  I just can't browse the local network share we have setup for custom nuget packages.  When I try I get the error:

`the path '\\someserver\somefolder' for the selected source could not be resolved`

I am able to access the file location through explorer and a mapped drive.  I tried removing and re-adding the network location in nuget package manager, but when I try to re-add it, I can't see the mapped network drive or use the full unc path (it throws error that the network location doesn't exist).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally!... the answer!

**The problem was running visual studio as administrator.**

The network share nuget was trying to access required my own user credentials, but running visual studio as administrator uses the local administrator credentials which didn't have access to the share.

There are a few ways to prevent VS from running as administrator (ex: if you're using a shortcut you need to go to properties and uncheck "run as administrator"), but since I had ran the compatibility troubleshooter on devenv.exe to force it to always run as admin, I didn't know how to undo it.  This link shows you how to do that:

https://superuser.com/a/547846/213179

Note: to see other reasons why not to run visual studio as administrator, read the posted question in the above link:

*"For those interested, the reason I want to go back is because some features (such as drag-and-drop files into VS, open files from Windows Explorer, etc.) no longer work."*

Comment: Perfect ! I too had the same issue. My Project always works in Administrator mode and I always open VS in admin mode. While opening as normal user, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Package Source must be given as wrong path.
Try this

- Go to references
- Right and Click on Manage Nu-get Packages
- On the top right you will see Package Source
- Package Source drop down will have a settings button over there
- Remove available packages
- In Machine wide package, **tick** Microsoft and .Net
- Remove available source package if the directory does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to access a mapped drive.  The fix for me was rather than accessing it by letter, to use IP:

`P:\NuGet\packages` change to `\\10.10.1.11\NuGet\packages`